# Нужна ли запятая в предложении с «больше чем»?

Tags: запятые

В предложении: «Прежний рекорд был превышен больше чем на два часа». Нужна ли запятая в «больше чем»?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не нужна. Нет прямого сравнения.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146 (пункт 4)

По примерам Розенталя можно сделать вывод, что запятая обычно ставится, если при изъятии "чем..." структура не страдает и предложение более-менее звучит:
*Гостей оказалось меньше.

Эта комната выше.

Вернулся раньше.*
Но не: *прежний рекорд был превышен больше*.

Как однозначно определить? Запятая ставится при наличии **логического ударения** на слове "больше" и паузы.

Comment: спасибо. написала без зпт.

Comment: Тут "более" гораздо лучше звучит.

Comment: На Грамоте в последнем абзаце все примеры с числами с "более" (кроме последнего, что связано, скорее всего, с отсутствием глагола): http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_68

Comment: @flossyU Спасибо здесь оформляется так: если ответ полезен, то треугольник вверх, а если решает проблему, то кроме треугольника ещё и зелёная галочка (она может быть лишь у одного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

> Тут "более" гораздо лучше звучит.

Это дело исключительно личного вкуса. Лично я свой личный вкус не стал бы навязывать другим.

А по Розенталю логичнее сделать вывод, что запятая не ставится тогда, когда нет **конкретного объекта противопоставления:**

> 4. Внутри сочетаний *(не) больше чем, (не) меньше чем, (не) раньше чем, (не) позже чем* и т. п., если они не содержат сравнения, запятая не
>    ставится.